# Bootstrap Stylesheet not applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

on some of my pages I have bootstrap included.

Now on one page, I have an alert included, styled by bootstrap.

It's defined as simple as that:

```
 $('#wrongPasswordDiv').html('<br/><div class="alert alert-danger" id="wrongPWAlert" role="alert">Falsches Passwort. Bitte erneut versuchen!</div>');
```

Also, before, Bootstrap css file is included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrapcss" />
```

`bootstrapcss` is routed to the correct css file.

In the network tab, you can see that loading bootstrap works fine:

[image: Screenshot]

But also, you can see, that even though it's loading, no classes are applied.

Now if I change the including of bootstrap to a CDN, it is working and the classes are perfectly applied.

Now I have no idea, what the problem is, becaue as you can see, bootstrap is loading and in both cases, it's loading, but only when loading from the CDN, the styles are applied.

Any ideas why?

**Edit:** after trying, if I load the CSS through the direct link instead of over the router, it's working. In another file, the same line is working perfectly fine though, so the routing seems to work fine (which you can see on the fact, that the file is loaded as well)

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to the `Content-type: text/css` header, like this question: [CSS files ignored when using HTML5 doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14688218/7586)

Comment: You're right, console says `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/bootstrapcss".`....
how can I manually set the Content-type then?`

Comment: @Kobi when I remove the `DOCTYPE`, then the css seems to be loaded correctly, even thought the warning in the console remains

Comment: You need to add the HTTP header as part of your route, it depends on your server. Chances are it would work automatically if you'd user static file host and a .css file and url.

Comment: I can't find a way to send HTTP Headers with `AltoRouter`, which is the routing plugin I'm using... I'll proapbly use the complete path to it or remove the DOCTYPE then

Comment: I wouldn't remove the doctype - it will probably break a lot of things, and IIRC bootstrap requires it to work correctly. I suggest you'd post a new question regarding the header and AltoRouter.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the point, you must go before the first slash in the address of the folder:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrapcss" />
```

Comment: and again, as mentioned, the /bootstrapcss is routed to the correct css file

Comment: Could you share the file

Comment: question is solved already now, I just postedthe answer from another thread, the problem was not about the path there, but about the routing, because the wrong MIME-type was sent by the router.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested and answered in another thread by Kobi, this is the answer to the question:

> Using this route:

```
$router->map('GET','/bootstrapcss','example.css','bootstrapcss'); And
```

> then while matching:

```
$match = $router->match();


 if($match['name'] === 'bootstrapcss'){
    header("Content-Type: text/css");
    $fileName = $match['target'];
    echo file_get_contents($fileName);
    return; }
```

Complete answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54002049/3375021).

Thank you for the help again!

Answer (score -2):

you are missing file extension in in html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap.css" />
```

Comment: As mentioned, the `/bootstrapcss` is routed to the correct css file