# AltoRouter send Mime Type

Tags: php, html, css, url-routing, altorouter

I'm using `AltoRouter` to route my urls to the correct files. Now basically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995715/bootstrap-stylesheet-not-applied), I describe my problem already.

On one page, I have an alert included, styled by bootstrap.

It's defined as simple as that:

```
$('#wrongPasswordDiv').html('<br/><div class="alert alert-danger" id="wrongPWAlert" role="alert">Falsches Passwort. Bitte erneut versuchen!</div>');
```

Also, before, Bootstrap css file is included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrapcss" />
```

`bootstrapcss` is routed to the correct css file using `AltoRouter` and this line of code:

```
$router->map('GET','/bootstrapcss','vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css','bootstrapcss');
```

Now, in console, it throws a warning saying `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/bootstrapcss"`.

If I use the complete path to the css file, a CDN  or remove the `DOCTYPE`, its working fine. But I don't wanna do either of those variations... Removing the doctype, might damage other functions and if I would use the complete css path, then I wouldn't need the routing...

Any ideas how I could send the `Content-type: text/css` header, in order to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the proper `Content-Type` before you send the response content. I don't know much PHP so I may not read the CSS in the best way, but this is a working example:

Using this route:

```
$router->map('GET','/bootstrapcss','example.css','bootstrapcss');
```

And then while matching:

```
$match = $router->match();

if($match['name'] === 'bootstrapcss'){
    header("Content-Type: text/css");
    $fileName = $match['target'];
    echo file_get_contents($fileName);
    return;
}
```

For context, I have a full example here: https://gist.github.com/kobi/09eaeeecb3406b193a84a674218798a9
This is based on the basic example on AltoRouter: https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/tree/master/examples/basic

Comment: @nameless - no problem! I felt bad because no one answered you yesterday, so I installed PHP on my VM `:P`. Turns out AltoRouter is a tiny router that relies on regular PHP for everything, so it was relatively straightforward.